# Error while simulating omnet network for 4096 node

Tags: networking, routes, nodes, omnet++

I am trying to simulate my network with more number of nodes. I tried simulating with 16, 64, 256, 1024 nodes. Till 256 nodes i was able to simulate the network properly. With network size of 1024 it took around half an hour to display the tkenv window but i was able to simulate. But with 4096 nodes it is loading for a long period of time and after that it will show IDE not responding and when i terminated the simulation through console it showed the following error:

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
Working directory: C:/Abhilasha/omnetpp-5.0/omnetpp-5.0/samples/routing/networks
Command line: ../routing.exe -r 0 -c General -n .. --debug-on-errors=false Torus.ini

Answer (score 1):

The error message simply says that you terminated the process, which you actually did.

Did you check the RAM usage for your simulation with 256 or less nodes?
My guess is that your simulation uses up all RAM on your system.
Are you using a 32- or 64-bit Windows version?

If you do not need the graphical display of the simulation, you could build and run your simulation for the command line environment. No graphics to display and the simulation normally runs much faster.

The OMNeT manual explains all you need to know about the different runtime environments and how to switch between them: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:run-sim:introduction